How do I apply a delta transform to a single bone?
I've got a character in Blender with a full skeleton.  There's an auxiliary (for lack of a better word) bone called Point003 which controls the character's weapon, which is grasped in his right hand for the length of the 51-frame animation.  In other programs it loads correctly, but in Blender, the bone and the weapon load with an offset, with the weapon's mesh appearing a short distance below the character's hand.  The bone & weapon mesh seem to be animating properly, but offset.
I need to apply a delta transform to translate this bone a short distance up the Z axis so that it's placed properly for the animation.  Any attempt I've made so far has tried to apply the translation to the entire skeleton, so the entire mesh moves, which doesn't work.
How do I fix this?

i recommend providing a blend file so we can see your settings and know what's going on.

Here's the blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/vm3f09iyskv3mif/SW.blend/file


disable autokeyframe
delete all keyframes on point003
move the bone in pose mode so that it is in his hand

result:


That worked, thanks @Chris.

you are welcome
